# How does Fisher work?

Tags: small-world-underground

Say I have four territories in a row along the river and the Fisher Special power. Are they worth 2 bonus coins or 3? If I have two territories that skirt the river but are non contiguous are they worth anything?

We were playing that their bonus is (# of river adjacent territories/2) but I suspect that each unique pair of adjacent territories that are both adjacent to the river counts. The terminology in the rules isn't clear enough for me to be sure either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Four territories in a row are worth 2 bonus coins.  Adjacency doesn't matter.**

Per the [FAQ](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?th=22605&start=0):

> **Q.** If a Fisher Race occupies 4 regions in a row that borders the river, does that count as 3 pairs (AB, BC, CD) ?
>
> **A.** No. That would count as 2 pairs, AB and CD. Note that these regions do not need to be adjacent to each other.